# PowerBI - Count of days where the sum of a column for that date is above 0.5

Tags: graph, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to put some data on a visualization.

I want a bar chart that has a list of computer labs on the x axis, and the "count of days where the sum of Util4 for that date is above 0.5 on the y axis

Some of the formulas for measures i've tried are:

`High Util = COUNTAX('Login Sessions', SUM('Login Sessions'[Util4]) >0.5)` doesn't work

`High Util2 = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Login Sessions', 'Login Sessions'[Util4] >0.5))` only counts lines where Util4 is above 0.5, doesn't sum to find dates where multiple rows for this date add up to above 0.5

I'm missing some math know how here, I know i need to incorporate StartDate into my measure somehow, but not sure how. Any advice would be appreciated.

**edit**: In my dataset i have unique 289 dates. Each row is a login session that happened on a computer in a computer lab. I want to sum all of the Util4 numbers for that specific date\computer lab combination and then count how many times each computer lab had that sum be above 0.5. I do not know the proper way to do this.

My expectation would be numbers between 0 and 289 for each computer lab, which i could then make a visualization to show which rooms had util4 above 0.5 (50%) the most often.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't sum to find dates where multiple rows for this date add up to above 0.5"? Please explain and also post your expected output.

Comment: Post had been updated with more information, hopefully this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Following will get you the sum of Util4 for each day/lab, add it as calculated column in your table:

```
Total Util =
VAR _Date = SELECTEDVALUE('Login Sessions'[StartDate])
VAR _Lab = SELECTEDVALUE('Login Sessions'[Ad Computers.Computer Lab])
RETURN 
   CALCULATE(
      SUM('Login Sessions'[Util4]),
      FILTER(
         ALL('Login Sessions'), 
         'Login Sessions'[StartDate] = _Date && 
         'Login Sessions'[Ad Computers.Computer Lab] = _Lab
      )
   )
```

Then create the following measure for the count:

```
_daysCount = 
   CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT('Login Sessions'[StartDate]),
      FILTER(
             ALL('Login Sessions'), 
             'Login Sessions'[Total Util] >0.5
      )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks. @pratikbhavsar Unfortunately this didn't work. I encounter the error "A circular dependency was detected: Login Sessions[Util4], Login Sessions[Total Util], Login Sessions[Util4]." for more context, my util4 column is a calculated column ```Util4 = DIVIDE([TotalMinutesUsed], [TotalMinutesAvailable], 0) TotalMinutesUsed = SUM('Login Sessions'[TotalMinDiff]) TotalMinutesAvailable = 480*[NumberOfBusinessDays]*[NumComputers]```